# how can I achieve a bottom navigation bar with these features?

Tags: flutter, dart

1. There are five navigation items in total and the widths are 154,153,154,153,154. I know it's kind of strange but the UI design is like this. As for this I guess I cannot use any Widget about `navigator` in the flutter lib.
2. Each item contains an `icon` and a `text` as usual but the distance between the two should be set exactly. I don't know if it can be set in flutter widget `bottomNavigatorBar`.
3. Commonly, the color of the icon, text and the background will change when selected.

What I have done: I created a widget and add it to the bottom of every pages. As you can imagine, when jumping to a new page, the navigation bar will re-render. That is not the same as we use in our mobile phones.

I have found some articles and blogs, but still can't solve my problem. Is there any reference?

Comment: can you add an Image of UI what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @AdithyaShetty it just look like common navigator but has unusual detailed requirement as I said. Or do you know how to maintain a navigation bar without using the widget provided by flutter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below code and redirect this page into main.dart and can use test and icon also.

```
class nav extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _navState createState() => _navState();
}

class _navState extends State<nav> {
  int tabIndex = 0;
  List<Widget> listScreens;

  @override
  void initState() {
    ScreenUtil.init(width: 375, height: 812);
    super.initState();

    listScreens = [
      Home(),
      Treatments(),
      Request(),
      Appointments(),
      Menu(),
    ];
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
          body: listScreens[tabIndex],
          bottomNavigationBar: new Theme(
            data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
                canvasColor: Color(0xFF320151),
                primaryColor: Color(0xFF320151)),
            child: BottomNavigationBar(
                backgroundColor: Color(0xFF38095c),
                selectedItemColor: Color(0xFFe34fd1),
                unselectedItemColor: Color(0xFF510382),
                currentIndex: tabIndex,
                onTap: (int index) {
                  setState(() {
                    tabIndex = index;
                  });
                },
                items: [
                  BottomNavigationBarItem(
                    title: Text(""),
                    icon: Container(
                        width: 154, child: Center(child: Icon(AntDesign.home))),
                  ),
                  BottomNavigationBarItem(
                    title: Text(""),
                    icon: Container(
                        width: 153,
                        child: Center(
                            child: Icon(MaterialCommunityIcons.medical_bag))),
                  ),
                  BottomNavigationBarItem(
                    title: Text(""),
                    icon: Container(
                        width: 154,
                        child: Center(child: Icon(Fontisto.share_a))),
                  ),
                  BottomNavigationBarItem(
                    title: Text(""),
                    icon: Container(
                        width: 153,
                        child: Center(child: Icon(AntDesign.calendar))),
                  ),
                  BottomNavigationBarItem(
                    title: Text(""),
                    icon: Container(
                        width: 154,
                        child: Center(child: Icon(Ionicons.ios_person))),
                  ),
                ]),
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much. your answer give me inspiration. I thought I can't change the width of each `BottomNavigationBarItem` but actually it can be designed.